# By what mechanism is a React Hook needed to be used at top level?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If I use the following code:

App.js:

```
import useFoo from "./useFoo";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let foo = 3;

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    foo = useFoo(6);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {foo}
    </div>
  );
}
```

where `useFoo()` is merely to return the square of a number:

useFoo.js

```
export default function useFoo(a) {
  return a * a;
}
```

This can be shown on https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-knuth-jwshws?file=/src/App.js

So:

1. if you keep on refreshing the resulting page, you do see a 3 and 36 at random, so it does seem like "a React Hook", in this case `useFoo()` doesn't need to be at top level
2. at work, I actually encountered a pattern which is

```
const [bar, useBar] = useBar(value1, value2);
```

and even thought it looks very similar to a `useState()`, I found that `useBar()` merely works like a function like `useFoo()` above. That is, it doesn't have the "keeping a state and `bar` will stay the same" kind of magic like `useState()`. (but on second thought, even useState() in fact gives a value back and assign it to the `value` in `const [value, setValue] = useState(value1)`, so there is real assignment going on, but just that `useState()` chooses to return the same value if no useBar() is called).

But the question is:

3. If I use the same thing:

```
let [bar, setBar];

if (true) {
  [bar, setBar] = useBar(value1, value2);
}
```

then the Visual Studio Code with error and warning messages built in will complain it is a bug: that React Hooks must be at the top level. However, if I run the webapp, it still runs as normal. So the question is:

Do all React Hooks need to run at the top level? If they do, then why does `useBar()` above work?

If only some React Hooks need to be at top level, then what determines that they must be at top level?  Is it just by linting really? (so if you ignore the linting, the program will run into unexpected results? I suppose it will give a lint error instead lint warning, so that on the GitHub review, your coworker won't approve it. But then, the `useBar()` above can work despite the lint error, if it exists. So what determines whether it must be top level or not?

(that is, I found that sometimes the Hooks or Custom Hooks are merely like a function. And if it is function, it really doesn't have the rule of needing to be at the top level).

Comment: Hooks should always be called at the top-level inside of a function component. Never place them inside of a nested scope. If you need a conditional, build it into the hook, not in the component.

Comment: so does that mean if the customer hook acts really like a normal function, write it as a function and not as a custom hook? I think I see sometimes these functions are written as custom hooks

Comment: A custom hook can call other hooks internally. They are typically created to store their own state and effect logic so that common; complex functionality can exist in one place. A custom hook can eliminate 10s, or even 100s of lines of boilerplate code within a functional component.

Answer (score 0):

React Hooks are functions that let you "hook into" React state and lifecycle features from function components. They allow you to use state and other React features without writing a class component. However, React Hooks must be called at the top level of a function component, before any early returns.

React relies on the order in which Hooks are called to maintain state and effects. Calling Hooks conditionally or inside loops can disrupt this order and lead to unexpected behavior. For example, if you call a Hook conditionally, React may not be able to track which Hooks have been called, and this can lead to errors.

In addition, calling Hooks inside loops can lead to performance problems. React will need to re-render the component every time the loop iterates, and this can be slow.

Therefore, it is best practice to always call React Hooks at the top level of a function component. This will help to ensure that your code is consistent and predictable.

```
function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(3);

  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    foo = useFoo(6);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {foo}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because having a predictable sequence is important.**

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function,
> before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that
> Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.
> **That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks
> between multiple useState and useEffect calls.**

[Source](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

And

> Instead, to enable their concise syntax, Hooks rely on a stable call
> order on every render of the same component. This works well in
> practice because if you follow the rule above (“only call Hooks at the
> top level”), Hooks will always be called in the same order.

[Source](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory#how-does-react-know-which-state-to-return)